# Bootstrap datatable no se alinea correctamente

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, bootstrap

Tengo un problema con una tabla de bootstrap, y es que el `header` no sale alineado con las columnas de la tabla y creo que es culpa del botón de búsqueda y lo de **Show x entries** si lo quito del **js** se alinea perfecto.

He probado a mirar en la propia web de *bootstrap* a ver si cometía algún error, pero esta todo correcto y no logro que se visualize como debería.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cabe decir que el `footer` si que esta perfectamente alineado.

Aquí mi código:

```
<table id="dtWorkers" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th></th>
                                            <th></th>
                                            <th></th>
                                            <th class="success" style="text-align:center" colspan="3">Dias Vacaciones</th>
                                            <th></th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>

                                            <th>Nombre</th>
                                            <th>Departamento</th>
                                            <th>Puesto</th>
                                            <th class="success">Ganados</th>
                                            <th class="success">Tomados</th>
                                            <th class="success">Restantes</th>
                                            <th>Opciones</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
 @foreach ($workers as $worker)
                                        <tr>
                                            <!--<td scope="row">{{$worker->id}}</td>-->
                                            <td>{{ucwords($worker->name)}}</td>
                                            <td>{{ucwords($worker->area->name)}}</td>
                                            <td>{{ucwords($worker->position)}}</td>
                                            <td class="success">{{$vacationDays=MyHelper::vacationDays($worker->date_in)}}</td>
                                            <td class="success">{{$vacationTaken=MyHelper::vacationTaken($worker->id)}}</td>
                                            <td class="success">{{$vacationDays-$vacationTaken}}</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <!-- Single button -->
                                                <div class="btn-group">
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                                        <i class="icon-calendar5"></i>
                                                        <span class="caret"></span>
                                                    </button>

                                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                                    <li><a href="{{ url('/vacation/create/'.Crypt::encrypt($worker->id).'/'.Crypt::encrypt($worker->name))}}" > Asignar Vacaciones</a></li>
                                                        <li class="divider"></li>
                                                        <!--crear ruta para editar usuarios desde el panel
                                                            <li><a href="{{ url('/worker/remove/'.Crypt::encrypt($worker->id) ) }}">Editar usuario</a></li>
                                                        --><li class="divider"></li>
                                                        <li><a href="{{ url('/worker/remove/'.Crypt::encrypt($worker->id) ) }}">Borrar usuario</a></li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    @endforeach
                                    </tbody>

                                    <tfoot>
                                        <tr>
                                        <th>Nombre</th>
                                        <th>Departamento</th>
                                        <th>Puesto</th>
                                        <th class="success">Ganados</th>
                                        <th class="success">Tomados</th>
                                        <th class="success">Restantes</th>
                                        <th>Opciones</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tfoot>
                                </table>
```

Y mi **js**:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#dtWorkers').DataTable({
    "scrollX": true,
});
<-- Si omito esto si que se alinea todo-->
$('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');
});   
 <!----->
</script>
```

Edito: Subo foto de lo que hace bt-select en js

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedes ver, el buscador de filas en la tabla y el Show 10 entries, es lo que carga ese bt-select, si lo omito en mi codigo se ve todo perfecto, pero si lo pongo me descuadra el header, sin embargo ahi va bien.

Aqui pongo el js que se encarga de añadir dataTables_Length,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Que es lo que no esta bien alienado? ¿Puedes enseñarnos una imagen de bien y otra de mal?

Comment: Arriba en mi post, tienes una imagen, si te fijas donde dice "Tomados", en el header, no cuadra con la casilla del body que tiene justo debajo, y lo mismo ocurre con las demas columnas. Si elimino la parte que ves encima del header, lo de "search: ..." y lo de "Show x entries" si omito eso del js, se visualiza todo alineado. te pongo una foto de como se veria si estubiera bien, pero creo que se aprecia bien. Saludos y gracias

Comment: He estado haciendo pruebas y me funciona perfectamente, ¿Has probado en otros navegadores? ¿Algun estilo que se este aplicando por algun otro componente?

Comment: Si, he probado en varios navegadores, tanto explorer, como safari, como chrome, y en ninguno lo visualizo bien. Que yo sepa no, simplemente el javascript, lo que yo añadi a mas sobre la tabla fue el doble header, y el js. Aparte de usarlo en laravel

Comment: En este caso creo que bootstrap podría solucionar tu problema. Te recomiendo que leas el sistema de [Grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) y lo utilices para ordenar tu tabla.

Comment: Ya esta haciendo uso de Bootstrap, y especificamente de las clases para tablas en bootstrap, que son lo optimo para construir este tipo de componentes; esta respuesta realmente no aporta valor a la pregunta

Comment: Aqui he hecho una recreacion rapida de lo que nos das, y se ve todo bien. ¿Que añade la clase bs-select? En el ejemplo que te paso no veo que tenga efecto alguno: https://jsfiddle.net/r9najotd/

Comment: Creo que el problema va a ser ese, yo si que veo lo que añade el bt select. Edito mi post para que te des cuenta, pero hay no reproduce el error que me sucede a mi

Comment: Por favor muestra que es lo que incluye la clase `bs-select`; probablemente hay estilos en esa clase que estan dando problemas; tambien muestra en donde lo estas agregando, pues en tu codigo no se ve ningun elemento con la clase `dataTables_length` a la cual le estes agregando la clase

Comment: @IvanS95 El elemento `dataTables_length` es añadido por datatable al ejecutar la función

Comment: Exactamente, pego ahora el codigo de esa clase a ver si la encuentro.

Comment: Edito, y por lo que veo eso lo añade jquery no bootstrap.. no entiendo nada..

Comment: Necesitamos saber que hace ese bs-select, podrias reproducir el problema en algún sitio publico para que podamos "trastear?

Comment: Podria darte todos los scripts que tengo añadidos a ver si asi te falla, osea, darte la pagina html completa  otra idea no se me ocurriria, siendo laravel, tendria que hacer una instalacion completa en algun vps y darte acceso, podria hacerlo pero me llevaria tiempo, la otra opcion es que se conectase a mi pc a traves de tv o anydesk...

Comment: Sigues sin mostrar que estilos añade la clase `bs-select`, es ahi donde probablemente esta el problema

Comment: Haciendo pruebas he averiguado que la clase bs-select, no añade nada a la tabla o al html, de hecho lo omito del codigo y sigue trabajando todo exactamente igual.